# Analytics with AWS Amplify and Pinpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

Currently working implementing web and mobile analytics via AWS Amplify and Pinpoint.

I've noticed that analytics section of the Amplify docs for JS differs from the related section for iOS and Android, specifically in the extra parameters/keys/values that an event object can include.

JS docs specify an `attributes` property, while the iOS and Android versions both specify something referred to as `properties`. See snippets below:

**JavaScript**

```
Analytics.record({
    name: 'albumVisit', 
    // Attribute values must be strings
    attributes: { genre: '', artist: '' }
});
```

**iOS**

```
func recordEvents() {
    let properties: AnalyticsProperties = [
        "eventPropertyStringKey": "eventPropertyStringValue",
        "eventPropertyIntKey": 123,
        "eventPropertyDoubleKey": 12.34,
        "eventPropertyBoolKey": true
    ]
    let event = BasicAnalyticsEvent(name: "eventName", properties: properties)
    Amplify.Analytics.record(event: event)
}
```

**Android**

```
val event = AnalyticsEvent.builder()
    .name("PasswordReset")
    .addProperty("Channel", "SMS")
    .addProperty("Successful", true)
    .addProperty("ProcessDuration", 792)
    .addProperty("UserAge", 120.3)
    .build()

Amplify.Analytics.recordEvent(event)
```

Are `attributes` and `properties` interchangeable? I'm going to be using Amazon QuickSight to build out analytics dashboards, ultimately the collected event data will end up on S3, and queried using Athena. I'll need to define a schema for the table in Athena and I'm uncertain, based on the above, what format I can expect the data `attributes`/`properties` to be in. It seems like Amazon intended for `attributes` and `properties` to contain the same type of event-related information. But I'm confused as to why the naming convention differs between platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS & Android, Amplify Analytics' String & Boolean **properties** are mapped to Pinpoint [**attributes**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/apps-application-id-attributes-attribute-type.html). Double & Integer properties are mapped to Pinpoint [**metrics**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/analytics-standard-metrics.html).

Or, expresssed as a table:

| Amplify property type (in) | Pinpoint type (out) |
| --- | --- |
| String | Attribute |
| Boolean | Attribute |
| Integer | Metric |
| Double | Metric |

(Refer to Amplify's [Android code](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/blob/1d9df013f97c2ff98c02251464b444d2e6f2f4e4/aws-analytics-pinpoint/src/main/java/com/amplifyframework/analytics/pinpoint/AWSPinpointAnalyticsPlugin.java#L247-L257), [iOS code](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/blob/02ac2ba5c417883ea90f3d59b3cd28e63d2a1d39/AmplifyPlugins/Analytics/AWSPinpointAnalyticsPlugin/Support/Extensions/AWSPinpointAnalyticsPlugin%2BAWSPinpointEvent.swift#L15-L23).)

Answer (score 1):

On the off chance someone else notices the lack of explanation around this in their doc's... any `property` added via the mobile SDKs will appear within the `attributes` object in the record event payload.